# Primacy of Rash"i

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, rashi, history

How did [Rash"i](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi)'s commentary on the Torah become the primary (phrasing intentionally vague) commentary among the hundreds of others that have been written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ramban refers to Rashi as "Lo Mishpat HaBechora" -- he has the rights of the firstborn.  I think he's chronologically the first major commentary we have ... okay what about R' Saadiah Gaon ... I think R' Saadiah is more strictly translating words?  Or is it that they didn't have R' Saadiah Gaon's commentary in Europe?

Comment: That was Ramba"n.

Comment: Rav Saadiah gaon's commentary was not universally accessible- it was in Arabic. 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saadia_Gaon#Works

Comment: You are most welcome - I am sure you would have figured it out yourself knowing your record on m.y.!

Answer (score 1):

Simply due to its clarity - short and to the point + covering almost everything